# Mysql most outer table visibility in nested loops

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume i have 4 tables:
'users' (id, username),
'photos' (id, user_id, name),
'photos_comments' (id, photo_id, user_id, text),
'photos_likes'    (id, photo_id, user_id, test).

I want to calculate sum of all comments and likes for every user in all of his uploaded photos. For that i'm trying to build a query:

```
SELECT users.*,
    (SELECT SUM(count) as rating FROM(
   SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM photos_likes
     WHERE photos_likes.photo_id IN (SELECT photos.id FROM photos WHERE photos.user_id = users.id)
            UNION
   SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM photos_comments
     WHERE photos_comments.photo_id IN (SELECT photos.id FROM photos WHERE photos.user_id = users.id)
 ) as total_rating) as rating FROM users
```

It returns 'Unknown users.id column in WHERE clause' error. So it looks like it can't see users table in most inner query.I can't understand why it happens,because another similar query works ok:

```
SELECT users.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM photos_likes
  WHERE photos_likes.photo_id IN (SELECT photos.id FROM photos WHERE photos.user_id = users.id)) as likes_count,

   (SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM photos_comments
     WHERE photos_comments.photo_id IN (SELECT photos.id FROM photos WHERE photos.user_id = users.id)) as comments_count FROM users
```

In this query it can grab id from users table row in most inner query. Why is it working like that? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [Subqueries in the FROM Clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/from-clause-subqueries.html):

> Subqueries in the FROM clause cannot be correlated subqueries, unless used within the ON clause of a JOIN operation.

In your second example, you use the subquery in a `where` clause. That's the difference.

See also [Correlated Subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    photos.userid, 
    photos.photoid, 
    count(distinct commentid), 
    count(distinct likeid),
    count(distinct commentid) + count(distinct likeid) as total
from
    photos 
         left join photos_comments on photos.photoid=photos_comments.photoid
         left join photos_likes on photos.photoid=photos_likes.photoid
group by photos.userid, photos.photoid
```