# MySQL : Access to "root" value within a sub-sub-query

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, parent

I have a little problem on a MySQL query, and I've don't find the answer on the site for the moment (maybe I miss it ?)

The problem is to retrieve a value of the root parent, within a sub-sub query..

Quickly, the project is an ads manager. I want to find the money spent in the month, for one campaign, that can contains multiple ads, and each ad can have a different price.
So, the result is grouped by Campaign, but the money spent must be grouped by Ad before being grouped by Campaign ; I need to get some other informations, that's why I make a subquery.

The actual query is :

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(l.lgs_mkt_user_campaign_keyid) AS nbClics, 
    l.mkt_user_ad_keyid,
    a.mkt_user_ad_ppc,
    a.usr_user_keyid,
    r.mkt_rel_user_campaign_ad_score,
    c.mkt_user_campaign_ppm,
    (
        SELECT SUM(usr_user_money_spent) FROM (
            SELECT 
                (a2.mkt_user_ad_ppc * COUNT(l2.lgs_mkt_user_campaign_keyid)) AS usr_user_money_spent
            FROM
                lgs_mkt_user_campaigns l2
            LEFT JOIN
                mkt_user_ads a2 ON a2.mkt_user_ad_keyid = l2.mkt_user_ad_keyid
            WHERE
                l2.mkt_user_campaign_keyid = l.mkt_user_campaign_keyid
            GROUP BY
                l2.mkt_user_ad_keyid
        ) AS Sub
    ) AS usr_user_money_spent
FROM
    lgs_mkt_user_campaigns l
LEFT JOIN
    mkt_user_ads a ON a.mkt_user_ad_keyid = l.mkt_user_ad_keyid
LEFT JOIN 
    mkt_rel_user_campaigns_ads r ON r.mkt_user_ad_keyid = l.mkt_user_ad_keyid
LEFT JOIN 
    mkt_user_campaigns c ON c.mkt_user_campaign_keyid = l.mkt_user_campaign_keyid
WHERE
    l.lgs_mkt_user_campaign_datecrea BETWEEN '2012-11-01' AND '2012-11-30'
    AND l.lgs_mkt_user_campaign_is_clic = 1
GROUP BY
    c.mkt_user_campaign_keyid
```

The problem is on the line 17, in the WHERE clause : `l2.mkt_user_campaign_keyid = l.mkt_user_campaign_keyid`

The alias "l" can't be handle by the sub-sub query (I don't find any other solution to achieve this...)

I don't really want to write another subquery in this WHERE clause, to retrieve the same `l.mkt_user_campaign_keyid`, I think it would be a bad idea because it would give a huge request "just" for that...

Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this ?

Many thanks, and 1) Sorry for my english ;), 2) Sorry if the solution is already on stackoverflow, I didn't find it :/

**[EDIT]**

Some details to explain the subquery :

- `mkt_user_campaigns` : contains all campaigns, and user as foreign key
- `mkt_user_ads` : contains all ads, and user as foreign key
- `mkt_rel_user_campaigns_ads` : binds the ads with the campaigns
- `lgs_mkt_user_campaigns` : logs all clicks on an advertisement

The principal query retrieve some informations about campaigns, and I need to know how much a campaign has cost.
The subquery attempts to retrieve the cost of each campaign.

Subquery with more details :

It attempts to find, for a campaign, all ads which be clicked, how many times, and the final cost (ppc = price per click). Here, the WHERE clause miss some details, like the datecrea of the log, but I lightened it to be more readable.

This subquery must return the result for the same Campaign that the principal query, that's the difficulty here

Comment: what exactly error did you get when run this query?

Comment: I got : `#1054 - Champ 'l.mkt_user_campaign_keyid' inconnu dans where clause`

Comment: so there is a column called mkt_user_campaign_keyid into table lgs_mkt_user_campaigns?

Comment: Yes, this field is used on the last `LEFT JOIN` too, and if I remove the subquery, the request works fine :)

Comment: what your innerquery exactly do? explain it

Comment: Maybe, my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13192853/1741542 about correlated subqueries in a from clause helps.

Comment: @pkachhia : I edit my question, I hope it's better

Comment: @OlafDietsche : I don't see how I can add a JOIN here to help me... Seems to be another example of subsubquery

Comment: It is the same. It basically says, that you cannot use your outer/root table in a subquery in a from clause. So, you cannot solve your problem in this way.

Comment: @OlafDietsche : I followed your advise, and I change the query ; I wrapped the principal query in the subquery, and now it works good :) Thanks for your time !

Comment: If it helped, please +1 my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13192853/1741542. Thanks.